# how to display images from (block content) rich text in portable text

Tags: reactjs, next.js, bots, sanity

how to display images from (block content) rich text in portable text using sanity as backend and next js as front end.

my portable text look like this

```
<PortableText
 value={blog.body}
/>
```

no variable or const are associated with it.

display all text and other fields expect images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass an object of components to render your custom content types such as images.

First, create an object for your PortableText custom components, and return your image component for the `image` type.

```
const myPortableTextComponents = {
  types: {
    image: ({ value }) => {
      return (
        <SanityImage {...value} />
      );
    },
  },
};
```

Second: Create your ImageComponent. I'm using the `next-sanity-image` plugin here to use the image with NextJS Image component.

```
import {useNextSanityImage} from 'next-sanity-image'
import Image from 'next/image';

const sanityConfig = sanityClient({
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
  dataset: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET,
  useCdn: true
});

const SanityImage = ({ asset }) => {
  const imageProps = useNextSanityImage(sanityConfig, asset);

  if (!imageProps) return null;

  return (<Image 
    {...imageProps}
    layout='responsive'
    sizes='(max-width: 800px) 100vw, 800px'
  />);
}
```

Finally, pass the custom components object to your PortableText component via the `components` prop.

```
<PortableText
  value={body}
  components={myPortableTextComponents}
/>
```

You can learn more about rendering PortableText in React [here](https://www.sanity.io/docs/presenting-block-text#c8e78c624f83) and more about the next-sanity-image plugin [here](https://www.sanity.io/plugins/next-sanity-image)

Comment: is sanityimage avaliable for next js?

Comment: You can use the next-sanity-image plugin to use Sanity Image with the next.js image component: https://www.sanity.io/plugins/next-sanity-image

Comment: I have updated my answer to include next-sanity-image